# Indexing in MATLAB with vectors

Tags: matlab, indexing

I am trying to index a matrix (image read with `imread()`) with vectors for `row` and `column` numbers.

`map` is the image read with `imread()`, and `rows` and `columns` are the 1-dimensional index vectors.

But when I do `map(rows, columns)` it returns a 2-dimensional matrix, where I presume it is using every single permutation of `rows` and `columns` to index `map`.

How do I index `map` with each corresponding element at `(rows,columns)`?

I believe the answer I am looking for is equivalent to `diag( map(rows,columns )` but it's a bit inefficient I think.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right what you want is to extract a vector of pixels where each pixel is a combination of row and column index.

If I got you right, the way to do it is using [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).
You can do something like that (Assuming Image is Grayscale Image):

```
vPixelIdx = sub2ind(size(mInputImage), vRowsIdx, vColIdx);
vPixels = mInputImage(vPixelIdx);
```

I didn't test it as I don't have access to MATLAB now, but it should work.